# how to show image in ng-2 table

Tags: angular, datatable

New to AngularJS. I want to display an image in ng2 table but as html is not in my hands in this, I am unable to do so. The code is attached below.

Service File

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class SmartTablesService {
      smartTableData = [
        { img: 'assets/img/sky-bg.jpg',
          packageid: 21,
          orderid: 'Mark',
          lastName: 'Otto',
          username: '@mdo',
          email: 'mdo@gmail.com',
          age: '28'
        }
];
        getData(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(this.smartTableData);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
}
```

Component File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { SmartTablesService } from './smartTables.service';
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';

import 'style-loader!./smartTables.scss';

@Component({
  selector: 'smart-tables',
  templateUrl: './smartTables.html',
})
export class SmartTables {

  query: string = '';

  settings = {
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="ion-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="ion-close"></i>',
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="ion-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="ion-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="ion-close"></i>',
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="ion-trash-a"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true
    },
    columns: {
      img: {
        title: 'img',
        type: 'html',
        valuePrepareFunction: (img) => { return `<img src="img" />` }
      },
      packageid: {
        title: 'Package ID',
        type: 'any'
      },
      orderid: {
        title: 'Order ID',
        type: 'string'
      },
      lastName: {
        title: 'Last Name',
        type: 'string'
      },
      username: {
        title: 'User Name',
        type: 'string'
      },
      email: {
        title: 'Email ID',
        type: 'string'
      },
      age: {
        title: 'Age',
        type: 'number'
      }
    }
  };

  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

  constructor(protected service: SmartTablesService) {
    this.service.getData().then((data) => {
      this.source.load(data);
    });
  }

  onDeleteConfirm(event): void {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }
}
```

thanks in advance for the favour.

Answer (score 1):

First the library you're using is ng2-smart-table.

You should modify your return statement on valuePrepareFunction like this (2 ways):

1.When using ` ` you can pass the value like this ${img}.
es. { return `<img src="${img}" />` }

2.You can use ' ',
es `{ return '<img src="' + img + '" />' }.`

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}      

imageUrl: {
    title: 'image',
    filter: false,
    type: 'html',
    valuePrepareFunction: (imageUrl) => {
        return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<img src="${imageUrl}" alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="50">`);
    },
}
```

Comment: Working Fine For Me

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.